# How to reload format-box in CKEDitor 4 dynamically?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to populate the format-box in CKEditor toolbar dynamically (depending on what the user selects in another select box).
Is it possible to change the options of the format-combo box dynamically , without reloading the whole CKEditor ?

Answer (score 0):

The shortest answer is: no. However...

The plugin responsible for this box is [the format plugin](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/format/plugin.js). It gathers all the data during the `init` function called when editor is being initialized. If you want to have this thing dynamically populated, you need to change some logic of this plugin on your own.

You might be interested in `onRender` callback for rich combos which is used by the plugin to dynamically change the value of the combo. Another handful thing might be [add() method](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/richcombo/plugin.js#L337) of rich combo used by format plugin. I'm pretty sure you got to extend the richcombo plugin to remove items.

Good luck anyway!